# Why is File.isAbsolute() platform dependent when the File class is platform independent?

Tags: java, file

From the `File` class JavaDoc:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.
>
> User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent pathname strings to name files and directories. This class presents an abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical pathnames.

Why is the method `.isAbsolute()` platform dependant? (return different result for `/tmp` on Win and Linux) and doesn't check if the file is absolute either or Linux or Windows? How can the `File` class guess which platform's file I am trying to represent via the `File` in my code? I am not necessarily representing *local* file system's file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to have some idea of which platform you're interested in, and the current platform is a pretty good guess!

On Linux `/tmp` is absolute. On Windows it isn't - it's relative to your current drive.

Comment: /tmp in windows is CURRENT_DRIVE_LETTER:\tmp, isn't it? I consider this absolute path same as c:\tmp

Comment: @Jan although windows would search a relative path in the current drive, it still is a relative path.

Comment: @Jan: `/tmp` in Windows can refer to several different locations, depending on what the current directory is (e.g. `C:\tmp` or `D:\tmp`). I'm pretty sure that this fact makes it a relative path.

Comment: My feeling is that windows has multiple ROOT file system and the roots are the drives, like c:, a: etc. If so then I would still consider /tmp as absolute on windows, otherwise you can say /tmp is relative to root on linux :) But will be gratefull on any clarification here

Comment: @Joachim makes sense ... but still not convinced 100% :)

Comment: @Jan: not convinced about what exactly?

Comment: @Joachim when /tmp on windows is relative to root (one of the roots) it looks to me similar as /tmp is relative to root (even though there is only one) on Linux. But agree that it can refer to different locations depending on under which root you are working on. That makes it "half-absolute".

Comment: @Jan: "relative to root" is meaningless on Linux. The root is **always** `/`, so "relative to root" always means "relative to /" which is an absolute position specification.

Comment: @Jan, your first response is like saying `blah` (note, no `/`) is the same as `CURRENT_DIRECTORY/blah`, so it's absolute.

Comment: @Jan, ref your second response. Yes, Windows has multiple roots. But that doesn't make `/tmp` absolute. To be absolute means that it cannot have multiple meanings. `/tmp` CAN have multiple meanings. If you have `C:/tmp` and `D:/tmp`, then `/tmp` will mean different things depending on whether your cwd is somewhere on C: or somewhere on D:. And that's NOT absolute.

Comment: @dty right, you convinced me :) +1 for you and Joachim for being patient

Comment: It _used_ to be considered absolute.  This is a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not necessarily representing local file system's file

Then you should not use `File`, `File` provides easy access to the local filesystem and is not meant to represent non-local resources.

There are other System independent classes like [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) and [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) you should use instead(URL has some design flaws so prefer URI).

Comment: The javaDoc states: This class presents an abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical pathnames.

Comment: @Jan Zyka Yes and then it goes on about how the representation of path names differs between Windows and Unix systems. File works as long as you don't mix systems as the path String is system dependent (thanks to things like File.separator).